# templates which contain instantiations of themselves, recursion in C++

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

very quick question, let's say I have a template:

```
template <class T>
class foo {

 private:
   T SubFoo;
  ...

};
```

And then I have things like:

```
 foo < foo < int > > myFoo;
```

which works fine. In this case, myFoo would have a member called myFoo.SubFoo which would have the type `foo < int >`.

I would like to have a pointer in myFoo.SubFoo that points to myFoo. I don't know how to properly call this, a class-member pointer of SubFoo that points to the whole mother class, myFoo. Is this possible? I tried to include the declaration:

```
template <class T>
class foo {

 private:
  ...
   T SubFoo;
   foo< foo < T > >* p2mother; 
  ...

};
```

But this does not seem to work.

In general, what I am doing is setting up a recursive structure. It's quite easy to pass communication down the recursion but I am finding trouble going "upwards". Maybe I am designing this wrongly in the first place.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `But this does not seem to work` .. but it [works](http://ideone.com/ujxKR). What are trying to achieve and what is the problem ?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It seems to work for me (at least in VS2010)

Comment: Did you try to write `foo* p2mother;` inside foo class declaration?

Comment: Seems that you do not plan to accept any answer, so don't you plan to upvote any. :(

Comment: sorry what? I did accept them and upvoted them. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general case (this works in g++):

```
template <class T>
struct foo {

 //...
 T SubFoo;
 foo* p2mother; 
 //...
};

foo< int > simple;
foo< foo< int > > complex;

int main() {

  simple.p2mother = &simple;
  complex.p2mother = &complex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Instead of a comment) this works in VS2010, gcc-4.3.4

```
template <class T>
struct foo {
   T SubFoo;
   foo< foo < T > >* p2mother; 
};

foo<int> foo_instance;

foo<foo<int> > foo_foo_instance;

int main()
{
  foo_instance.p2mother= &foo_foo_instance;
}
```

Comment: It seems you are right. I was getting a compilation error over and over again and now it's gone. I don't know what I was doing...thanks a lot.